# Javascript / JQuery loop through posted ajax data string to assign new values to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which updates a database via ajax.   My issue is then how to update the data displayed on the page to show updated details. The POST data can vary and therefore the datastring would be something like this:

```
        var dataString = '[name resource we are editing]=1' + 
        '&para1='+ para1 + 
        '&para2=' + para2+
        '&para3=' + para3
```

I want the function below to split or loop through each of the POST variables in the datastring to update the text of an element on the page.  I cannot figure out how.

```
function editAccount(dataString, details, form){
        status = $(".status");
        $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>/edit/",  
          data: dataString,  
            success: function(response) { 
                $.each(response, function(key, value) { 
                success_code = key;
                message = value;
               });

              if(success_code == 1){
                status.text(message).addClass("valid");
                //show details and hide form
                $("#" + details).show();
                $("#" + form).hide();   
                            //HOW to do below?
                //update details being displayed with datasource data 
                //loop through dataString to assign eg. $('#para1')text(para1);

              } else {
                status.text(message).addClass("invalid");
              }
            },
            error: function(response){ 
            status.text("There was a problem updating your details into our database.  Please contact us to report this error.").addClass("invalid");
          }  
        });  

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you declaring `dataString` as an object, instead of a String, if you can. You could construct it like this `{name_resource: value, param1: value...}`, the ajax call would still work and the object would be much easier to iterate over than a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a previous comment, I would suggest declaring the `dataString` variable as an object:

```
var dataString = { '[name resource we are editing]' : 1, 
        'para1': para1, 
        'para2': para2,
        'para3': para3
        }
```

Now it'll be much easier to loop over the params, just using the function `each`, for instance, which you already use in your code:

```
$.each(dataString, function(key, value) {
    // Do stuff with each param
});
```

EDIT:

As @Qpirate suggests, you also can use the javascript `for` loop:

```
for(var key in dataString){
    // value => dataString[key]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest doing a `for(x in dataString)` this way you could do a switch on the `x` which will be the Name of the property, otherwise you are just working with index's which can get messy.

Comment: @Qpirate not in this case: `$(dataString).each...` would work as you say, but the function `$.each()` works fine for this purpose. From the docs: `jQuery.each(): A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.`

Comment: Learnt something new. didn't know it would function like that. thanks.

Comment: Anyway, using javascript native methods or loops is always an advantage, so +1 for you

Comment: thanks I didnt know I could pass the POST parameters as an object like so.  Its all works, thanks.